# Variables multiplied to roots

Tags: notation, radicals, convention

If I have to write $2$ times square root of $x$, I would write it as $2\sqrt{x}$.

However, if I have $x$ times the square root of $2$, would I write it as $x\sqrt{2}$ or $\sqrt{2}x$? Is there any rule or convention that exists(like writing $3xy$ instead of $xy3$)?

Comment: They are the same.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I know they are, I want to know which is the convention.

Comment: I think we have no any convention about this thing.

Comment: Personally, I like it if the variables are on the right, so $\sqrt{2}x$ looks better than $x\sqrt{2}$ to me. But I wouldn't call the other way wrong...

Comment: *Technically* $x\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}x$ are the same but because it is easy to confuse $\sqrt{2}x$ with $\sqrt{2x}$, $x\sqrt{2}$ is clearer and is preferred.  (I would not say "convention").

Comment: @user247327 or at least write $\sqrt 2\,x$ ...

Comment: @user247327 That's the main reason why I asked it here. On one of my tests I confused $\sqrt{2}x$ and $\sqrt{2x}$ and got that question wrong.

Comment: Being aware of the ambiguity is decent protection against confusion, because at least you can ask what is meant if you notice it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not a well-established convention. Sometimes, if I write $\sqrt2x$, I'll put a downward stroke at the end of the square root sign to show more clearly where it ends. Another solution is to use a dot:

$$\sqrt2\cdot x$$

or to use exponential notation:

$$2^{1/2}x$$

If you just put the $x$ in front ($x\sqrt2$), nobody would say you're wrong, or if they do, they haven't really got a leg to stand on.

I'd be inclined to put the variable after the coefficient in many cases, though, particularly if I'm writing out a polynomial:

$$3x^2+\sqrt2x+9$$

just to keep it in the usual format.

Comment: Seems it is pretty justified for polynomials for keeping the form.